# Deleting row from grid view with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql

I have 4 tables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and I have references from `a` to `b`, `b` to `c` and `c` to `d` (via foreign keys).
I am using grid view to load this table.
If I try to delete a value having a reference then it gives me an exception:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint 'FK__b__sc__0519C6AF'. The conflict occurred in database 'dbs', table 'dbo.b', column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I don't want to delete the value if there is a key associate with it. Can  `GridViewSim_RowDeleting()` help?

I have the same problem when I update. I am using the standard link provided by grid view to update and delete.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the execption in the `RowDeleted`/`RowUpdated` events so it isn't thrown to the application. e.g.

```
void GridViewSim_RowDeleted(Object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Exception == null)
    {
        //Delete was successful - Do Something
    }
    else
    {
      // Delete was not successful - Do something else
      e.ExceptionHandled = true;   
    }
}
```

You could also do this in the `RowDeleting` event as you have said, but this would require custom validation to check if the primary key existed in child tables, it would be easier and faster, and in my opinion no less messy to let the foreign keys do their job and catch the exception, rather than perform checks to pre-empt the error.